# How to limit Omnisharp to loading a single project?

Tags: visual-studio-code, omnisharp

How to limit Omnisharp to loading a single project?

I am using the Cake plugin for VSCode https://cakebuild.net/docs/integrations/editors/vscode/

In my set-up, I have a build.cake at the root of my project, with a sln in a src/ directory, followed by several .csproj files in further subdirs.

The problem I'm having is that when I start Omnisharp selecting 'Cake' as the project, Omnisharp goes and loads ALL the subdirectories and causes unusable slowdown and frequent crashing. I am not interested in using VSCode on my src/ dir, ONLY my build.cake for completion and debugging.

Is there any way to configure Omnisharp to only load code for the current project?